# add validation rule checking conditions

Tags: codeigniter

I have defined a validation rule like

```
protected $add_rules = array(
        'add_question' => array(
            'field' => 'add_question',
            'label' => 'lang:topic.add_question_error',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
        )
    );
```

I have to add extra rules in this class if user is not logged on like

```
if(!isset($this->current_user->id)){
    'username' => array(
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'lang:topic.username',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
        )    
}
```

How can i add this second rule within the first protected class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add it to the `$add_rules` array you need to do

```
if(!isset($this->current_user->id)) {
    $this->add_rules['username'] = array(
        'field' => 'username',
        'label' => 'lang:topic.username',
        'rules' => 'trim|required'
    );
}
```

Because it is a `protected` property you will only be able to manipulate it in the same class or any class that extends it